# Better Line Removal in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing text data from many sources, and I need to remove the blank lines regardless if the line ending is \r\n, or just \n, but the ugly method below is the only way I have found to clean up the line-endings with spaces between them. Here's the code I am using. And I know this can't be the best way to do it, but I have struck out with regex so far. What's the best way to do this?

```
    text = text.replace('\r', '[EOL]')
    text = text.replace('\n', '[EOL]')
    for x in range(0, 30):
        text = text.replace("[EOL]        [EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text = text.replace("[EOL]       [EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text = text.replace("[EOL]      [EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text = text.replace("[EOL]     [EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text = text.replace("[EOL]    [EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text = text.replace("[EOL]   [EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text = text.replace("[EOL]  [EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text = text.replace("[EOL] [EOL]", "[EOL]")
        text = text.replace("[EOL][EOL]", "[EOL]")
    text = text.replace("[EOL]", "\r\n")
```

Comment: Maybe `re.sub(r'\s*[\r\n]', '\n')`? If that doesn't work, please include some example input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `re.sub`

```
re.sub(r'[\r\n]+[ \t]*[\r\n]*', r'\n', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

For 'blank' lines defined as any line where you can't see text, try

Find  `(?m)$\s+^`
Replace  `\r\n`